# Loop subset over several files in a directory and output files into a new directory with a suffix

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I have figured out some part of the code, I will describe below, but I find it hard to iterate (loop) the function over a list of files:

```
library(Hmisc)
filter_173 <- c("kp|917416", "kp|835898", "kp|829747", "kp|767311") 
# This is a vector of values that I want to exclude from the files
setwd("full_path_of_directory_with_desired_files")
filepath <- "//full_path_of_directory_with_desired_files"
list.files(filepath)
predict_files <- list.files(filepath, pattern="predict.txt") 
# all files that I want to filter have _predict.txt in them
predict_full <- file.path(filepath, predict_files)
# generates full pathnames of all desired files I want to filter
sample_names <- sample_names <- sapply(strsplit(predict_files , "_"), `[`, 1)
```

Now here is an example of a simple filtering I want to do with one specific example file, this works great. How do I repeat this in a loop on all filenames in `predict_full`

```
test_predict <- read.table("a550673-4308980_A05_RepliG_rep2_predict.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
# this is a file in my current working directory that I set with setwd above
test_predict_filt <- test_predict[test_predict$target_id %nin% filter_173]
     write.table(test_predict_filt, file = "test_predict")
```

Finally how do I place the filtered files in a folder with the same name as original with the suffix filtered?

```
predict_filt <- file.path(filepath, "filtered") 
 # Place filtered files in 
filtered/ subdirectory
filtPreds <- file.path(predict_filt, paste0(sample_names, "_filt_predict.txt"))
```

I always get stuck at looping! It is hard to share a 100% reproducible example as everyone's working directory and file paths will be unique though all the code I shared works if you adapt it to an appropriate path name on your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work to loop through each of the files and write them out to the new location with the filename specifications you needed. Just be sure to change the directory paths first.

```
filter_173 <- c("kp|917416", "kp|835898", "kp|829747", "kp|767311") #This is a vector of values that I want to exclude from the files

filepath <- "//full_path_of_directory_with_desired_files"
filteredpath <- "//full_path_of_directory_with_filtered_results/"

# Get vector of predict.txt files
predict_files <- list.files(filepath, pattern="predict.txt") 

# Get vector of full paths for predict.txt files
predict_full <- file.path(filepath, predict_files) 

# Get vector of sample names
sample_names <- sample_names <- sapply(strsplit(predict_files , "_"), `[`, 1)

# Set for loop to go from 1 to the number of predict.txt files
for(i in 1:length(predict_full))
{
  # Load the current file into a dataframe
  df.predict <- read.table(predict_full[i], header=T, sep="\t")

  # Filter out the unwanted rows
  df.predict <- df.predict[!(df.predict$target_id %in% filter_173)]

  # Write the filtered dataframe to the new directory
  write.table(df.predict, file = file.path(filteredpath, paste(sample_names[i],"_filt_predict.txt",sep = "")))
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer. The loop worked fine for what I intended to do. Just a few caveats for any future readers, I wanted to filter rows corresponding to the `filter_173` vector in the variable `target_id`, so it was important to add a `,` at the end. Also in your `write.table`, `sep` should come after the file function is closed with a `)` The default in `write.table` somehow has `quotes = T` and `row.names = T`. This would break your future scripts if they are sensitive to " " in tab delimited files (which I am guessing they will be).

Comment: So effectively following is the loop that worked:

`for(i in 1:length(predict_full))
{
  # Load the current file into a dataframe
  df.predict <- read.table(predict_full[i], header=T, sep="\t")

  # Filter out the unwanted rows
  df.predict <- df.predict[!(df.predict$target_id %in% filter_173), ]

  # Write the filtered dataframe to the new directory
  write.table(df.predict, file = file.path(filteredpath, paste(sample_names[i],"_filt_predict.txt"),sep = "\t", row.names=F, quotes=F))
}`